# What are the anomaly detection algorithm (supervised or unsupervised) that I can use for the following images?

Tags: deep-learning, autoencoder, yolo, anomaly-detection, generative-adversarial-network

[image]
The Normal Image

[image]
The Anomaly Image

I have tried using CNN Autoencoder for anomaly detection. I trained it with just the normal images and then tried to test the model on anomaly images and used reconstruction error to classify the image as an anomaly or not, but the autoencoder is not able to reconstruct the normal images properly.

Comment: Have you tried using bigger networks or larger datasets? The image seems to be extremely complex so small networks may not be able to extract meaningful features from it.

Comment: What kind of data is this representing? Could be there are better alternatives than encoding as images

Comment: I would first try a pretrained model like MobileNet, and do an MLP autoencoder on the image embeddings that it outputs.